# Modify the second duplicate record based on date

Tags: sql

I have the database below:

Invoice_id | Invoice_date

```
111     | 2017-10-05   
222     | 2017-10-01  
222     | 2017-10-02  
333     | 2017-10-26  
444     | 2017-11-16  
555     | 2017-11-02  
666     | 2017-09-03  
777     | 2017-07-30  
777     | 2017-07-31  
888     | 2017-12-04
```

This is what I need:

For all duplicate values (that have the same Invoice_id) change the most recent one (the one with the most recent date) to InvoiceID ++1;

Example: if the Invoice_id =222 shows up twice, the duplicate record with the most recent date (in this case 2017-10-02) needs to be updated to the Invoice_id of 223.

Comment: What happens when you want to change the value to 223 and there is already a 223?

Comment: and what if you have more than 2 duplicated invoiceId?

Comment: I haven't even though of that. Can we assume that we don't have such records?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  SQLite and SQL Server are quite different.  Tag with the database you are really using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toudpate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by invoice_id order by invoice_date) -
 1 as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set invoice_id = invoice_id + seqnum
    where seqnum > 0;
```

In SQLite, it would look more like:

```
update t
    set invoice_id = invoice_id + 1
    where exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.invoice_id = t.invoice_id and t2.invoice_date < t.invoice_date
                 );
```

Actually, this will also work in SQL Server.

Note:  Neither of these guarantee collisions against another invoice.  You should probably fix the table and then add a unique constraint/index to prevent duplication in the future:

```
create unique index unq_t_invoiceid on t(invoice_id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't care about collisions you can do this with ROW_NUMBER pretty easily.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    Invoice_id int
    , Invoice_date date
)

insert #Something values
(111, '2017-10-05')
, (222, '2017-10-01')
, (222, '2017-10-02')
, (333, '2017-10-26')
, (444, '2017-11-16')
, (555, '2017-11-02')
, (666, '2017-09-03')
, (777, '2017-07-30')
, (777, '2017-07-31')
, (888, '2017-12-04');

with SortedResults as
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Invoice_id order by Invoice_date)
    from #Something
)

update SortedResults
set Invoice_id = Invoice_id + RowNum - 1

select * 
from #Something
```